# Web.config: Values for ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a  asp-mvc-application, but all form/UI-Code ist made with angularJS (validation... ) , no html-helpers. Do ein need the entries 
ClientValidationEnabled and UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled
in Web.config? 
Or can I set this entries to false?

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ar as I understand, these entries are used efficiently with html helpers, but if you manually validated with AngularJS, it is not necessary to use those entries.